# Unable to marshal host object to interpreter space

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to run this code, to get only the schedules that already started and not ended:

```
schedules.Where(x=> DateTime.Today >= x.StartDate && DateTime.Today <= x.EndDate)
```

`schedules` is of type `List<Schedule>`

and the object `Schedule` has these 2 properties `StartDate` and `EndDate`, both of type `DateTime`.

So, on this line, I'm getting the error "Unable to marshal host object to interpreter space".

Can anyone help me understand why and what it means?

I tried to use `DateTime.Compare()` or changing `DateTime.Today` to `DateTime.Now`, nothing helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to set a variable with the value `DateTime.Today` and pass it to the Linq.

```csharp
var today = DateTime.Today;
schedules.Where(x=> today >= x.StartDate && today <= x.EndDate)
```

Still have no explanation for this, but it works.